# dynamic array dimension in golang

Tags: go, golang-migrate

I am trying to create a high dimension array in Golang.
Does anyone know how to do it?

e.g.

- `dims := [3,2,1]` as a parameter -> want `high_dims_array := make([3][2][1]int, 0)`
- `dims := [2]` -> want `high_dims_array := make([2]int, 0)`
- `dims := [3,3]` -> want `high_dims_array := make([3][3]int, 0)`

Where the `dims` is a variable containing dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks my friends. I have figured out a way to do this

```
func initialCube(shape []int) []interface{} {
    // base condition
    if len(shape) <= 1 {
        dim := shape[len(shape)-1]
        retObj := make([]interface{}, dim)
        for i := 0; i < dim; i++ {
            retObj[i] = 0.0
        }
        return retObj
    } else { // recursive
        dim := shape[len(shape)-1]
        retObj := make([]interface{}, dim)
        for i := 0; i < dim; i++ {
            retObj[i] = initialCube(shape[:len(shape)-1])
        }
        return retObj
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like what [`dolmen-go/multidim`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/dolmen-go/multidim) does (it helps to allocate a slice with the required number of elements):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/dolmen-go/multidim"
)

func main() {
    var cube [][][]int
    multidim.Init(&cube, 8, 2, 2, 2)

    fmt.Println(cube)
}
```

Output:

```
[[[8 8] [8 8]] [[8 8] [8 8]]]
```

You can also use a function (still with the same library) to initialize your 3*2 slice:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/dolmen-go/multidim"
)

func main() {
    var a [][]int

    multidim.Init(&a, func(i, j int) int {
        return 2*i + j + 1
    }, 3, 2)

    fmt.Println(a)

    var r [][]string

    multidim.Init(&r, func(i, j int) string {
        return "foobar"[i*3+j : i*3+j+1]
    }, 2, 3)

    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Output:

```
[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]]
[[f o o] [b a r]]
```

Comment: thanks, but in my question dims is unkonw..which means I can't have var a [][]int at first place . the dimension is a parameter

Comment: @EnXie you would need to iterate on your dims, and use make to make a slice of your slices.